# Navigating back to parent activity in ActionBar without handling Up button event

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have two activities that I want this navigation to happen, they are VendorsActivity and QuestionsActivity. The following how my AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

(I am not using the full name of my activities like `com.hello.world.MyActivity` as I am defined `package` attribute in `manifest` node.)

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".VendorsActivity"
        android:label="@string/vendors_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TestsActivity"
        android:label="@string/tests_activity_title"
        android:parentActivityName=".VendorsActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".VendorsActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/questions_activity_title" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

And in `TestsActivity`, I am calling `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` method from within `onCreate` method.

The problem is, it won't work unless I implement the following method in `.TestsActivity` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(TestsActivity.this);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But Android Developer Guide says that I don't have to handle the Up button's event as mentioned at the very bottom of hit page: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

> Because the system now knows MainActivity is the parent activity for
>   DisplayMessageActivity, when the user presses the Up button, the
>   system navigates to the parent activity as appropriate—you do not need
>   to handle the Up button's event.

**Edit and Answer:**

As Android Developer Guide says:

> Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical
>   parent of each activity by specifying the android:parentActivityName
>   attribute in the  element.
>
> If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support
>   Library with your app and add a  element inside the
>   . Then specify the parent activity as the value for
>   android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY, matching the
>   android:parentActivityName attribute.

So I think my problem was because of two reasons:

1. Running the app on a proper emulator. I was targeting a higher version but the emulator was running on API 14 (Android 4.0) so it didn't know how to handle `android:parentActivityName` attribute.
2. Targeting the right API level in Project Build Target properties as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

android:parentActivityName attribute supported only after API level.

One alternative is using [support-library:v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) combined with [NavUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html).

There is a great training material about this topic (include compatibility issue).
please check 
- http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

That being said, i am posting my code below because it is working :-

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.activitydatasend;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                intent.putExtra("first", "first");
                intent.putExtra("second", "second");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
package com.example.activitydatasend;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Second extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String a = bundle.getString("first");
        String b = bundle.getString("second");
        System.out.println(a+b);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activitydatasend"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activitydatasend.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activitydatasend.Second"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.activitydatasend.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/click"
        android:text="Click" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Even though you answer were not what exactly I am looking for, because of the link you provided, I am marking yours as the answer but I added more information to my own question which describes the solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you receive an error similar to

```
E/NavUtils﹕ getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName
```

or

```
does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)
```

You will probably need to change android:value to the full path.
So instead of

```
 <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
```

do

```
 <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.package.SecondActivity" />
```

Answer (score 4):

you can add metadata in manifest to support pre JellyBean OS.

```
<meta-data
     android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
     android:value=".VendorsActivity" />
```

Answer (score 2):

What API version are you using? In my experience, for older versions it *is* necessary to handle the up button event yourself, whereas with later versions it's done for you.

I haven't looked into which exact version changes this, but I know that API 13 *doesn't* handle it for you, while API 16 *does*.